# Combine 2 Django Querysets

Tags: python, django

I want to merge two queryset in Django using operand "|" but it don't work. I know that to do it you must have querysets from the same model. This is exactly what I'm trying to do. The loop is because I want to get random objects and merge it into one. Anyone have idea why Django throw "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Sentence' and 'Sentence'" error?

According to below source this is how to make it happen:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/06/20/django-tip-5-how-to-merge-querysets.html

```
from random import randint
from sentences.models import Sentence

sentence_number = 3

first_pk = Sentence.objects.first().pk

last_pk = Sentence.objects.last().pk

for i in range(sentence_number):

    next_pk = randint(first_pk, last_pk)
    sentence_qs = Sentence.objects.get(pk=next_pk)
    type(sentence_qs)

    if i > 1:
       sentence_qs = sentence_qs | Sentence.objects.get(pk=next_pk)
```

Comment: You're merging two `objects` and not two `querysets`. Try replacing `get` with `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not near an interpreter but, you're merging two objects and not two querysets. Try replacing get with filter. from random import randint

```
from sentences.models import Sentence

sentence_number = 3

first_pk = Sentence.objects.first().pk

last_pk = Sentence.objects.last().pk

for i in range(sentence_number):

    next_pk = randint(first_pk, last_pk)
    sentence_qs = Sentence.objects.filter(pk=next_pk)
    type(sentence_qs)

    if i > 1:
       sentence_qs = sentence_qs | Sentence.objects.filter(pk=next_pk)
```

Comment: You are right. Now I have queryset class and merge works. Thanks!